# Start Windows Form Project using simple text editor?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, project

I want to start a Windows Forms Project (VB.NET) using a simple text editor like notepad. I'm not interested in creating a button and other controls from scratch, I just want to know how to create a form, initializing controls without using the wizard.

My question is, is it possible? if it is possible, what are the necessary steps? Is there a tutorial for this? also, how to use command-line to compile the whole project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible as long as you include the proper namespaces

Answer (score 0):

You can can create it, using any text editor, but why would you like to do that , you can user express editions of visual studio if you don't want to buy a pro version.

Comment: If I know Windows forms project intimately, if I encounter unusal problems debugging will be easier.

Comment: Do you mean the designer that allows you to drag and drop the controls onto screen?  You can get to this code from VS by clicking the “Show All Files” button on the solution explorer then looking at the Form1.Designer.vb file.

You can do your “Write from Scratch” approach here if you like; it will even display the changes on the designer screen.